# Reassign a new object to a property

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties

When I initialise a property, I assign a delegate. When I assign a different object to this property do I need to reassign the delegate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the 2nd wave, you're not assigning it's delegate, whereas you do when you create the first wave.  I'd guess that that's part of your problem, without being able to see what's going on in the wave itself.

Comment: When you create the first wave you have `self.currentWave.delegate = self;`  When you create the second wave, you don't.  So whatever the wave is using the delegate for, won't happen.